# How to find a specific value from a column in Data Frame in Python using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to extract value of requirement number from a column named "Linked Projects" in a dataframe. This column "Linked Projects" contains a string in the below format:

```
Linked Issues  
Requirement-12345, NewPr-8795, OldPr-78941  
MSR-85749, Requirement-74852, NewPr-95418

Requirement-894895  

OldPr-85974, NewPr-968572, Requirement-985785
```

*Expected Result:*
What I want is to store the the requirement number in a new column like below:

```
Requirement Number  
Requirement-12345  
Requirement-74852  

Requirement-894895

Requirement-985785
```

Comment: If in all columns Requirement is written properly you can use regex and extract from each row using `df.apply()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get values with `regex` - `r'(Requirement-\d+)'` string with integer for get first matched value per row:

```
df['new'] = df['Linked Issues'].str.extract(r'(Requirement-\d+)')
print (df)
                                    Linked Issues                 new
0      Requirement-12345, NewPr-8795, OldPr-78941   Requirement-12345
1       MSR-85749, Requirement-74852, NewPr-95418   Requirement-74852
2                              Requirement-894895  Requirement-894895
3  OldPr-85974, NewPr-968572, Requirement-985785   Requirement-985785
```

If possible multiple values per row use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Linked Issues'].str.findall(r'(Requirement-\d+)').str.join(', ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution, you are a great help. It worked perfectly fine. I checked some document and need to confirm that here we used **r**  in r'(Requirement-\d+) to let the python know that we are dealing with a regular expression.